# Regular Expression to match sequences of one or more letters except for a specific value

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Looking for some help with a Regular Expression to do the following:

- Must be Alpha Char
- Must be at least 1 Char
- Must NOT be a specific value,  e.g. != "Default"

Thanks for any help,
Dave

Comment: @JS Bangs: Why do you think it is homework?

Comment: What language/regex variant are you using?

Comment: By 'alpha' do you mean alphabetical or alphanumerical? Do you mean 'a-z' or should this work with foreign alphabetic characters too?

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!Default)[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: Definately not homework - Maybe my kids will have this as homework someday! 

Thanks for the help Mark.

Dave

Comment: that solution is OK if you have a single specific value, but if you're comparing to a list of specific values (eg: dictionary words) the solution becomes untenable.

Answer (score 0):

Solve this in two steps:

1. compare against the regular expression `[a-zA-Z]+` which means "one or more of the letters from a-z or A-Z
2. if it passes that test, look it up in a list of specific values you are guarding against.

There's no point in trying to cram these two tests into a single complex regular expression that you don't understand. A good rule of thumb with regular expressions is, if you have to ask someone how to do it, you should strive to use the least complex solution possible. If you don't understand the regular expression you won't be able to maintain the code over time.

In pseudocode:

```
if regexp_matches('[a-zA-Z]+', string) && string not in ['Default', 'Foobar', ...] {
    print "it's a keeper!"
}
```